# Altered Carbon/ Takeshi Kovacs tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I am a little bit confused about the tag policy in case of book series vs adaptations:

We have currently tag [altered-carbon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altered-carbon) described as

> "For questions about Richard K. Morgan's novel "Altered Carbon" and its adaptations."

All good, we have one tag for the book and the Netflix series. However, Richard Morgan also wrote other books in this series: *Broken Angels*, *Woken Fury* and recently *Altered Carbon: Download Blues*

At the same time, Netflix continues to produce the second season of its adaptation (presumably based on the second book), which is **still** called *Altered Carbon*

So if I'd like to ask a question about, let's say, 3rd book, should I create [woken-fury](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woken-fury) and then [broken-angels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-angels) for questions regarding the 2nd one? Or maybe I should make [takeshi-kovacs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeshi-kovacs) encapsulating the whole series in a book form? If the latter, should the questions tagged [altered-carbon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altered-carbon) asking for the book version also be tagged with the [takeshi-kovacs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeshi-kovacs) while continuing to use [altered-carbon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altered-carbon) for the Netflix series?

Answer (score 5):

The pattern I've seen established with other works is to have a series/universe tag and, if required, a work tag.  For example, there's [the-lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings) for the series as a whole, and individual tags for the books: [the-fellowship-of-the-ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fellowship-of-the-ring), [the-two-towers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-two-towers) and [the-return-of-the-king](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-return-of-the-king).

I don't like [takeshi-kovacs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeshi-kovacs) as a series tag, since a tag should be clear about whether it refers to a work or a character; [takeshi-kovacs-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeshi-kovacs-series) is ugly, but less ambiguous.

That said, I would suggest we leave [altered-carbon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altered-carbon) as is, and update the usage to say that it applies to either the series of books or Netflix series *and* to the first book.  The advantage to not changing the current usage of the tag is that it doesn't require existing questions to be re-tagged.  Not adding a new series tag also avoids re-tagging.

(Further, if there aren't a lot of questions in the [altered-carbon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altered-carbon) tag, then maybe it's fine to use it for all the books, and just specify in a question if it's about a particular book.)